# How do you have an element fill the remaining height in vuetify 2.0?

Tags: vuetify.js

I am attempting to create a view where there is a top element with a secondary element vertically centered in the remaining space underneath it.

In my attempt, there is a section of whitespace that gets added below the second element which extends the height of the page instead of just filling it as intended.

A recreation of this issue can be found here: https://codepen.io/R3d4rmy/pen/BaBjvwy

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-app-bar app color="indigo" dark>
      <v-toolbar-title>Application</v-toolbar-title>
    </v-app-bar>
        <v-content>
            <v-container fluid class="fill-height">
        <v-row class="fill-height">
          <v-col
            cols="12"
            sm="10"
            offset-sm="1"
            md="8"
            offset-md="2"
            lg="6"
            offset-lg="3"
            xl="4"
            offset-xl="4"
          >
            <v-row class="fill-height">
                <v-col cols="12">
                  <v-row class="no-gutters">
                    <v-col cols="12">
                      <v-card class="mb-6" outlined>
                        <v-card-title>
                          Title
                        </v-card-title>
                        <v-card-text>
                          <div class="subtitle-2">
                            Subtitle
                          </div>
                        </v-card-text>
                        <v-divider class="mx-4"></v-divider>
                        <v-card-text>
                          <v-text-field
                            flat
                            single-line
                          ></v-text-field>
                        </v-card-text>
                      </v-card>
                    </v-col>
                  </v-row>
                  <v-row class="fill-height no-gutters" align="center">
                    <v-col cols="12">
                      <v-row class="no-gutters" justify="center">
                        <v-col align-self="center" cols="12">
                          <v-card class="mb-6" outlined>
                            <v-card-title>
                              Why is there extra whitespace below this v-card?
                            </v-card-title>
                            <v-card-text>
                              <div class="subtitle-2">
                                And how do I get this v-card properly centered in the remaining space below the first v-card?
                              </div>
                            </v-card-text>
                          </v-card>
                        </v-col>
                      </v-row>
                    </v-col>
                  </v-row>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>

    <v-footer color="indigo" app>
      <span class="white--text">&copy; 2019</span>
    </v-footer>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

I feel I may be misunderstanding the syntax after the upgrade to 2.0 and not using v-row and v-col in the right way with fill-height. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you're using too many v-rows and v-cols. You can get rid of a lot of those if you just want one card after another stacked in a column. The revised codepen is here: https://codepen.io/CodingDeer/pen/KKPzxYW

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-app-bar app color="indigo" dark>
      <v-toolbar-title>Application</v-toolbar-title>
    </v-app-bar>
        <v-content>
            <v-container fluid class="fill-height">
        <v-row class="fill-height">
          <v-col
            cols="12"
            sm="10"
            offset-sm="1"
            md="8"
            offset-md="2"
            lg="6"
            offset-lg="3"
            xl="4"
            offset-xl="4"
          >
            <v-card class="mb-6" outlined>
              <v-card-title>
                Title
              </v-card-title>
              <v-card-text>
                <div class="subtitle-2">
                  Subtitle
                </div>
              </v-card-text>
              <v-divider class="mx-4"></v-divider>
              <v-card-text>
                <v-text-field
                              flat
                              single-line
                              ></v-text-field>
              </v-card-text>
            </v-card>
            <v-col cols="12" class="pa-0 fill-height" justify-self='center'>
              <v-row
                align="center"
                justify="center"
                class="fill-height"
              >
                <v-card outlined>
                  <v-card-title>
                    Why is there extra whitespace below this v-card?
                  </v-card-title>
                  <v-card-text>
                    <div class="subtitle-2">
                      And how do I get this v-card properly centered in the remaining space below the first v-card?
                    </div>
                  </v-card-text>
                </v-card>
              </v-row>
            </v-col>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>

    <v-footer color="indigo" app>
      <span class="white--text">&copy; 2019</span>
    </v-footer>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: I realized my wording was misleading. I'm looking to vertically center the second v-card in the remaining space underneath the first one without the page getting "pushed" down like is happening in my example.

Comment: So do you want the height to take up the height of your screen and not more?

Comment: I want the second v-card in the example to be vertically centered in the remaining height underneath the top v-card. I don't want it to take up the full remaining height, just centered.

Comment: Yep - I understand. I just wanted to check if you wanted the full container to be a certain height, because the card won't have that behavior unless the full container is taller than both of the cards combined. I've updated my code to produce the effect you're looking for.

Comment: `fill-height` vs `full-height` classes in your code?

Comment: Both class values for `v-container` and `v-row` should be "fill-height" rather than "full-height".